# How to select columns based on header in excel vba project

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently working on an Excel VBA project which merges data from multiple workbooks.

The workbooks are identical in terms of columns but have variable row lengths.

I would like to only extract data from Columns with the header "School Name", "Participants" and "Status". These are the cells B2, G2 and H2. Thus, effectively, I only want the data from columns B, G and H.

Currently, I extract data using a set range (B3:H80) and then delete the unwanted columns. How do I edit the source range to .usedrange and edit that accordingly?

I have attached the code below. Thanks for your help!

```
Private Sub MergeAllWorkbooks()
Dim MyPath As String, FilesInPath As String
Dim MyFiles() As String
Dim SourceRcount As Long, FNum As Long
Dim mybook As Workbook, BaseWks As Worksheet
Dim sourceRange As Range, destrange As Range
Dim rnum As Long, CalcMode As Long


' Change this to the path\folder location of your files.
MyPath = "C:\Users\" & Environ("username") & "\Dropbox\Folder1\"

' Add a slash at the end of the path if needed.
If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
    MyPath = MyPath & "\"
End If

' If there are no Excel files in the folder, exit.
FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "*.xl*")
If FilesInPath = "" Then
    MsgBox "No files found"
    Exit Sub
End If

' Fill the myFiles array with the list of Excel files
' in the search folder.
FNum = 0
Do While FilesInPath <> ""
    FNum = FNum + 1
    ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To FNum)
    MyFiles(FNum) = FilesInPath
    FilesInPath = Dir()
Loop

' Set various application properties.
With Application
    CalcMode = .Calculation
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

' Add a new workbook with one sheet.
Set BaseWks = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)
rnum = 1

' Loop through all files in the myFiles array.
If FNum > 0 Then
    For FNum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)
        Set mybook = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFiles(FNum))
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not mybook Is Nothing Then
            On Error Resume Next

            ' Change this range to fit your own needs.
            With mybook.Worksheets(1)
                Set sourceRange = .Range("B3:H80")
            End With

            If Err.Number > 0 Then
                Err.Clear
                Set sourceRange = Nothing
            Else
                ' If source range uses all columns then
                ' skip this file.
                If sourceRange.Columns.Count >= BaseWks.Columns.Count Then
                    Set sourceRange = Nothing
                End If
            End If
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not sourceRange Is Nothing Then

                SourceRcount = sourceRange.Rows.Count

                If rnum + SourceRcount >= BaseWks.Rows.Count Then
                    MsgBox "There are not enough rows in the target worksheet."
                    BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
                    mybook.Close savechanges:=False
                    GoTo ExitTheSub
                Else

                    ' Copy the file name in column C.
                    With sourceRange
                        BaseWks.Cells(rnum, "C"). _
                                Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = MyFiles(FNum)
                    End With

                    ' Set the destination range.
                    Set destrange = BaseWks.Range("B" & rnum)

                    ' Copy the values from the source range
                    ' to the destination range.
                    With sourceRange
                        Set destrange = destrange. _
                                        Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
                    End With
                    destrange.Value = sourceRange.Value

                    rnum = rnum + SourceRcount
                End If
            End If
            mybook.Close savechanges:=False
        End If

    Next FNum
    BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
End If

ExitTheSub:
' Restore the application properties.
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = CalcMode
End With

Columns("C:F").Delete

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
destrange.Value = SourceRange.Value
```

To

```
destrange.Columns(1).Value = SourceRange.Columns(1).Value
destrange.Columns(2).Value = SourceRange.Columns(6).Value
destrange.Columns(3).Value = SourceRange.Columns(7).Value
```